# I can' load my vendor in the symfony app kernel

Tags: json, symfony, github, packagist, vendor

i have created a vendor on github, and make it in packagist, load this in composer successfully, and perfectly installed in my vendor/company/nameBundle/ , but now i need to load it on the app/AppKernel.php of symfony, but it return me a 404 not found, this class does not exist

on my composer.json

```
"require": {
    "agazzi/rest-client-authenticator": "1.0.*"
}
```

this part is good

composer.json of my packagist Bundle

```
{
    "name" : "agazzi/rest-client-authenticator",
    "description" : "API restfull json authenticator client",
    "keywords": ["package", "composer"],
    "homepage": "http://v*****s.com/",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "W*****m R****t",
            "email": "w******.*****t@******.com",
            "homepage": "http://v*****s.com"
        }
    ],
    "support": {
          "email": "contact@packagist.org"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "Agazzi\\RestClientAuthenticatorBundle\\": "" }
    }
}
```

And my AppKernel.php

```
$bundles = array( 
    new Agazzi\RestClientAuthenticatorBundle\AgazziRestClientAuthenticatorBundle()
);
```

Any idea ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't know... but I install symfony 2.3, add in composer the bundle, run composer update and add the line in AppKernel and everything works.

It seems other stuff is wrong.

Give us more information about the 404 error.

Comment: I have recently merge fix of my composer.json,

Comment: Thank you for trying, i try to check if everything work correctly,

Answer (score 0):

Probably Symfony returns 404 because you don't have such route.
Run app/console and see the output. If no errors be sure your bundle has been loaded.